# How to stop Tomcat from processing old request / clear the cache?

Tags: apache, tomcat

In order to test the execution-time of some methods, I set around 250 requests to my backend, which uses Tomcat and Jersey.

Shortly after I realized that there was a mistake in the code, and changed it. Now I have to wait until Tomcat has finished processing all the previous requests. I tried restarting the Tomcat server and redeploying the backend, but no luck.

When i start the server it continues to process the "old" requests.

How do I flush the cache?